# How to see view that is too big?

Tags: swift, storyboard, xcode6

If you have an element such as a UITextView that is bigger than the scene it is on, you won't see some of the resizing handles for the UITextView.

Besides dragging the element around and eventually getting it sized correct, is there some way to see the parts of the element that have fallen off the scene?

Comment: First, if you're using Auto Layout, you shouldn't use those handles; adjust constraints instead. In case you still want to view the handles, you can change the view containing the `UITextView` to "Freeform". Make the view to be bigger than the `UITextView`. Then you can view the `UITextView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constrain it to fit the screen using AutoLayout, or put the whole view in a UIScrollView